# What is the "Problem size" for bubble sort and distribution sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, input, bubble-sort, counting-sort

EDITED: I mentioned earlier "input size" but I meant "problem size" I have edited my post.

There are two algorithms bubble sort and distribution sort and I think the problem size for bubble sort is "n-1" as the operation is performed "n-1" times and for distribution sort I think it is "n". But according to my professor he think bubble sort problem size is "n" and distribution sort problem size is "n-1". I would like to know am I right?

I looked up online and everywhere it says the bubble sort is performed "n-1" times and distribution sort has "n" operation, but my professor is saying the opposite and I am not able to understand him. Could anyone please explain to me if I am wrong or not?

```
  Bubble sort: 

    Algorithm1 BubbleSort(A[0..n – 1])
    // Input: Array A[0..n – 1] of numbers
    // Output: Array A[0..n – 1] of numbers sorted in non-decreasing order

   do
   swapped ← false
   for i ← 0 to n – 2 do
     if A[i] > A[i+1] then
       swap (A[i], A[i+1] )
       swapped ← true
     while swapped
       return A

  Distribution sort:
 // Input: Array A[0..n – 1] of numbers between L and U (with L ≤ U)
 // Output: Array S[0..n – 1] of A’s numbers sorted in non-decreasing order

  for j ← 0 to U – L do D[j] ← 0
  for i ← 0 to n – 1 do D[A[i] – L] ← D[A[i] – L] + 1
  for j ← 1 to U – L do D[j] ← D[j – 1] + D[j]
  for i ← n – 1 down to 0 do
     j ← A[i] – L
     S[D[j] – 1] ← A[i]
     D[j] ← D[j] – 1
     return S
```

I expect the problem size of bubble sort to be "n-1" and distribution sort to be "n", but according to my professor it is wrong. I was wondering what is  the right answer for the problem size of bubble sort and distribution sort algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

This is both - very confusing question and very confusing answers.

In both cases you need all the input, so the input size is `n`, also its connected to the complexity theory where `n` has the same complexity as `n-1` and therefore it does not matter.

And in case of how many times it is executed, then bubble sort is executed up to `O(n^2)`, distribution sort groups more than one sorting alghorithm, but there is no sorting faster than `O(n*log n)`

PS: If this comes from high school professor, there is good chance he does not have full understanding of complexity theory either.

Comment: Could you give me some more general information, so I can prove myself that I am right? as it can help me pass one course as I only need 2 marks to pass

Comment: @Hemlata - I think neither fo you is correct - Input size is `n` in both cases, can you send me some link that shows that input size is `n-1`. Or give me more details about your task?

Comment: I couldn't find on any website about input size, neither it says on any website what is the input size for both of these algorithm, so I can't provide the link :( And my task was: Your report must describe your choice of ‘problem size’ applicable to both algorithms. That's what I was suppose to write based on the two algorithms. And even if input size is n then my one answer is still correct according to you, right?

Comment: Also, could you please have a look at my another question as well? I asked half an hour before, thanks.

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/Web/People/pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/aa/index.html

Comment: I have left the link above please have a look at it. Also, I just noticed it is "problem size" not "input size". Are they both the same thing? and at most places it says that "n-1" comparison are made (bubble sort) Link: http://iiitdm.ac.in/old/Faculty_Teaching/Sadagopan/pdf/DAA/new/SortingAlgorithms.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The "problem size" means the size of the input.  What the algorithm does doesn't affect it.

You are thinking incorrectly when you argue that BubbleSort has a different input size than DistributionSort when they take the *same* input.  The size of the problem/input is the problem/input size.

You are also thinking incorrectly when you try to figure out whether *n* or *n-1* is correct.  We haven't even specified any units -- *n* or *n-1* what?  And in all cases in real life there is also some constant amount of additional space taken up by the input that we don't even count. (stack frame pointer, etc.)

When we don't count these things, because of how we're going to use this "size" only in expressions of asymptotic notation, there is just no difference between *n* and *n-1*.

Comment: Could you please tell me then what is the correct answer for the problem size of both of these algorithm?

Comment: Since there is no difference between *n* and *n-1*, you should use *n*, because it's simpler.  You wouldn't say *n-1* when you know that the *-1* doesn't matter.

Comment: So, input size is “n” for both the algorithm, right? But like you said -1 doesn’t matter so Does my answer is correct as well?

Comment: Okay, but if “n” is the answer then my one of the answer is right though?

Comment: If you were asked "what is the problem size" in both cases, and you answered *n* in one case, then that case may be considered correct, unless a more accurate answer like "Θ(n)" was required.